# AppleScript: Get list of windows on all desktops

Tags: user-interface, automation, window, applescript, osx-lion

I need to get a count of all windows per application.  Every way I've tried to do this, I only get a count of windows that are assigned to the current (Mission Control) Desktop.  (I'm currently running Mac OS X 10.7, so post-Spaces.)  Is there any way to get a per-application count of all windows across all Desktops?

The crux of what I've tried:

```
tell application "System Events"
  repeat with _app in (every process whose visible is true)
    tell _app
      log (name as string) & ": " & (count of every window)
    end tell
  end repeat
end tell
```

Note that the `whose visible is true` clause isn't the problem.  It finds all of the appropriate processes, but once I ask the processes for windows, they only count the ones in the active Desktop.

I've tried pulling the `log` line out of the `tell` and using `name of _app` and `count of every window of _app`, but there's no difference.  I've tried grabbing things other than `process`es from `System Events`, but anything useful ends up effectively being just a different way to get the same object.  I've tried iterating over `UI elements`, but no windows show up that aren't on the current Desktop, though I do get a menubar for each application.

I'm fine with iterating across all Desktops (though not actually switching to all of them), but I can't even find a way to get a list of Desktops.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18707251/147202) claims to describe how to do that, but I only ever get a single element inside `every desktop`.  Not that there's an obvious way to get windows once you have that Desktop object anyway.

It's also worth pointing out that desktops are controlled by the Dock, and not by Mission Control.  I'm not aware of any way for AppleScript to talk to the Dock, so if you know of something, then an answer or comment about that might help point me in the right direction.

Am I trying to do something impossible?

Comment: By 'desktops', do you mean multiple monitor desktops or virtual desktops (available via mission control in 10.7)? That other question is dealing with multiple monitor desktops only.

Comment: Good point.  I meant Mission-Control-style Desktops.  Apple overloading this noun makes searching for solutions *really* easy. :/

Comment: So I discovered that you can get the number of (assumed: virtual) desktops using the following tcsh one-liner: `@ x = ( \`strings ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist | grep -c '^\$'\` + 1 ); echo $x`.  Try it and see if that works for you, as I'm not sure this hacky method is reliable. I'm running Mojave and it seemed to be accurate for me. If it works, you should be able to use keystrokes in an applescript to switch desktops and collect window names.

Comment: Bumping an old thread...Anybody ever found a solution to this?
Edit: possibly within AppleScript...

Comment: @hepcat72 , I tried your oneliner. I opened a terminal window (bsh) and ran tcsh. I pasted in your line. The number returned was 32. I currently have 20 open desktops, plus the dashboard, and right now nothing full screen. However, looking in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist` is a good idea.

Comment: I have tweaked my one-liner since that last comment. I wrote a very difficult to read perl 1-liner, or I'd describe it in detail, but the surrounding applescript sets a variable called `numClusteredDesktops` to its output minus the number of monitors plus 1. If that result is less than 2, then I do pretty much the same as above, but with `sort -u` added in the series.

Comment: Geez. I should have just looked at my code comment above it: This logic may not be right. It may just randomly work in my use case on 2 computers.  The logic is that `strings ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist` returns (either) a cluster of contiguous UIDs that includes each desktop and monitor, so the number of desktops can be discerned by subtracting the number of monitors and adding back 1 for the main monitor (or, if there are no secondary monitors, it returns non-contiguous UIDs for each desktop only).  There's also the assumption that each full screen app gets a desktop UID

Comment: So looking closer with that comment in mind, my perl perl one-liner creates groups of UIDs that appear on adjacent lines and returns the largest group. Then the applscript surrounding it does the `- numMonitors + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

As the **OP** is over six years old and I am unable to test under **OS X 10.7**, which is what was being used at that time, nonetheless, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me under **macOS Catalina** and returned the correct *window count* across all **Desktops/Spaces**, with the exception of any *application* that does understand the given **AppleScript** *command* and why the `try` and `on error` *statements* are being used.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    set appBundleIdentifierList to ¬
        the bundle identifier of ¬
            (every process whose visible is true)

repeat with appBundleIdentifier in appBundleIdentifierList
    try
        tell application id appBundleIdentifier to ¬
            set {appName, winCount} to {name, (count windows)}
        log appName & ": " & winCount
    on error errorMessage
        log errorMessage
    end try
end repeat
```

---

Sample *output* on my system that has multiple **Desktops/Spaces** with *windows* of the *application* on all or some of the **Desktops/Spaces** and the *window count* for each is correct across all **Desktops/Spaces**, not just the active **Desktop/Space** the *script* was run from.

```
(*Safari: 6*)
(*Terminal: 2*)
(*TextEdit: 4*)
(*Script Editor: 7*)
(*Finder: 3*)
(*BBEdit: 1*)
(*Norton Secure VPN got an error: every window doesn’t understand the “count” message.*)
(*Music: 2*)
```

---

**Notes:**

Not all *applications* are **AppleScript** scriptable, in that some do not contain an **AppleScript** *dictionary* within their *application bundle*.

Since the `application process` cannot return the correct number of *windows* across all **Desktops/Spaces**, this method relies on the `application` to return the number of *windows* across all **Desktops/Spaces**.

---

**Update:**

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* does the following:

- Gets the bundle identifier of every process whose visible is true.
- For each bundle identifier, get its *name* and the *window* count by querying the *application* directly. 
   
  If the *application* understands the **AppleScript** *command*, then if goes to the next *item* in the `appBundleIdentifierList`  *list*. 
   
   If it does not understand, then the *window* count is calculated by the following:

  - Attempts to get an invisible *window* count as they would not show up on the **Window** menu of an *application*.
  - Calculates the *window* count by the number of windows shown on the **Window** menu of the *application*.
  - Failing these methods it get the *window* count by querying the *application process*, with is only accurate fo the active **Desktop/Space** and is included only for completeness of trying to ascertain the *window* count just using *basic vanilla* **AppleScript**.
  - Goes to the the *application* in the `appBundleIdentifierList` *list*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set menuName to "Window"

tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to ¬
    set appBundleIdentifierList to ¬
        the bundle identifier of ¬
            (every process whose visible is true)

repeat with appBundleIdentifier in appBundleIdentifierList
    try
        tell application id appBundleIdentifier to ¬
            set {appName, winCount} to {name, (count windows)}
        log appName & ": " & winCount & ¬
            " -- By querying the application directly."
    on error
        set winCount to 0
        set notVisibleWindowList to {}
        set errAppName to ¬
            name of application id appBundleIdentifier
        tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
            try
                tell application process errAppName
                    set notVisibleWindowList to ¬
                        (windows whose visible is false)
                    if notVisibleWindowList is {} then ¬
                        set winCount to ¬
                            length of notVisibleWindowList
                end tell
            end try
            try
                set theTargetMenuItemsList to ¬
                    the reverse of ¬
                        (get name of ¬
                            menu items of ¬
                            menu menuName of ¬
                            menu bar item menuName of ¬
                            menu bar 1 of ¬
                            application process errAppName)
            on error
                set theTargetMenuItemsList to {}
            end try
        end tell
        if theTargetMenuItemsList is not {} then
            repeat with anItem in theTargetMenuItemsList
                if contents of anItem is ¬
                    missing value then exit repeat
                set winCount to winCount + 1
            end repeat
            log errAppName & ": " & winCount & ¬
                " -- By querying the Window menu of the application process."
        else
            try
                tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to ¬
                    set winCount to ¬
                        (count windows of ¬
                            application process errAppName)
                log errAppName & ": " & winCount & ¬
                    " -- By querying the application process. " & ¬
                    "May not be accurate, verify as necessary."
            end try
        end if
    end try
end repeat
```

---

Running both versions of the *example* **AppleScript** *code* to show the difference in *output*:

First version of *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
(*Safari: 6*)
(*TextEdit: 4*)
(*Finder: 3*)
(*BBEdit: 1*)
(*Norton Secure VPN got an error: every window doesn’t understand the “count” message.*)
(*Music: 2*)
(*Sublime Text 2 got an error: every window doesn’t understand the “count” message.*)
(*DiskCatalogMaker got an error: every window doesn’t understand the “count” message.*)
(*Script Editor: 7*)
(*System Preferences: 2*)
(*VMware Fusion got an error: every window doesn’t understand the “count” message.*)
(*Activity Monitor got an error: every window doesn’t understand the “count” message.*)
(*Terminal: 2*)
```

Second version of *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
(*Safari: 6 -- By querying the application directly.*)
(*TextEdit: 4 -- By querying the application directly.*)
(*Finder: 3 -- By querying the application directly.*)
(*BBEdit: 1 -- By querying the application directly.*)
(*Norton Secure VPN: 0 -- By querying the application process. May not be accurate, verify as necessary.*)
(*Music: 2 -- By querying the application directly.*)
(*Sublime Text 2: 4 -- By querying the Window menu of the application process.*)
(*DiskCatalogMaker: 2 -- By querying the Window menu of the application process.*)
(*Script Editor: 7 -- By querying the application directly.*)
(*System Preferences: 2 -- By querying the application directly.*)
(*VMware Fusion: 1 -- By querying the Window menu of the application process.*)
(*Activity Monitor: 0 -- By querying the Window menu of the application process.*)
(*Terminal: 2 -- By querying the application directly.*)
```

As you can see even **Activity Monitor**, a native default **macOS** *application*, the **Window** menu had to be queried as the *application* directly didn't understand the basic `count windows` **AppleScript** *command*.

Although the output of the second version of the *code* was accurate across all **Desktops/Spaces** at the time it was executed, any *application* that has "By querying the application process. May not be accurate, verify as necessary." as part of its *output* only includes the *window* count of the active **Desktop/Space** it was executed form. The bottom line is using *basic vanilla* **AppleScript** there is no guarantee to get a complete accurate *window* count of every visible *application* unless all the *applications* at that time cen be queried directly. Querying the **Window** menu by its *application process* should also be accurate.

**With that said, I think other methods may need to be used to get an accurate count.**

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code, setting up the Applescript version to 2.4 (do that as a habit); on the first run, your code presented me with the appropriate count of all the windows per application.

This code is what I tried, and the results seem to be satisfactory. Is there something I'm not seeing?

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions


tell application "System Events"
    set my_list to {}
    repeat with _app in (every process whose visible is true)
        tell _app
            log (name as string) & ": " & (count of every window)
            set my_list to my_list & {name as string, count of every window}
        end tell
    end repeat
    log my_list
end tell
```

Comment: RE: "Is there something I'm not seeing?" --  There is nothing in the _code_ of this answer that requires `use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later` or `use scripting additions`. That said, the **OP** is using **OS X 10.7** so that first line of _code_ certainly isn't applicable! The problem with this answer is it completely missed the most important requirement: **Is there any way to get a per-application count of all windows across all Desktops?** This suffers from the same issue in that it only gets the _window_ count of the active **Desktop**, not all **Desktops**!

Comment: @user3439894, thanks for your reply. I take my answer back. Even when I can see all the Applications in the list, disregarding which Desktop they're in, the count value comes as 0 for Applications on Desktops other than Desktop 1.

Answer (score 0):

Lured by the old OP to solve my similar problem, the answers here inspired an experiment. I suspected my Sierra applescripts were struggling in  Catalina but since the OP was about Lion I realized something else was my problem. It was the in the way I scripted "System Events"! One version of my code basically asked for "every window of application" while the other asked for "every window of process". Those behave completely different with regards to how multiple desktops in mission control are referenced! The experiment tried counting windows in 3 ways:

```
Tell application "Script Editor"
   return count of every window of application "TextEdit"
  #return count of every window of application process "TextEdit"
  #return count of every window of process "TextEdit"
  --(uncomment whichever test your doing.)
end
```

The result was that both "process" and "application process" counted only windows of the current desktop space. But using "application"(without the word "process") returned values for every window on every desktop space!
I hope that helps!